# Normal mode Backspace and Delete

Tags: cut-copy-paste, insert-mode, normal-mode

If I have a file like this in Insert Mode (pipe is cursor):

```
Sunday
|
Monday
```

I can press Backspace or Delete to remove the empty line. However in Normal
Mode, neither of those work. I have been working around this by using `dd`, but
is a better option available?

Comment: Space or Return or about any other key won't work in normal mode either... `dd` **is** the way to delete a line in normal mode. What's wrong with that? Having said that, you can always remap Backspace or Delete to do what you want in normal mode if you wish to...

Comment: Quite sure it is duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `J`:

> Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines. Remove the indent and insert
>   up to two spaces.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J